# Ignored tags no longer gray out the questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ignored-tags, question-lists

It seems a new change was made to SuperUser, where questions with tags on my ignore list are now almost as visible as regular questions. In fact, they seem to pop out more than the non-ignored questions.

This completely negates the purpose of using the ignore feature. How can I make these question less visible again, like it used to be, or otherwise completely filter them off the list?

See the image, there's nearly no distinction anymore between the middle and outer questions.

[image]

This is the same here on MSE and likely all other sites in the network. Can this please be reverted like it was before, so it's grayed out?

This is how it used to look before:

[image]

Comment: For completely removing them you can edit your ignore list and choose "Hide question ..." https://i.stack.imgur.com/DziW9.png

Comment: Thanks. Although I actually do prefer to see the questions, for now it just doesn't work for me to see them. Way too distracting. I'll hide them for now.

Comment: Eh, this looks like a bug. It used to be greyed out and that's what the interface to ignore tags promises. They've been changing this part of the interface lately and this wouldn't be the first time that they messed up the colors accidentally (or even on purpose :p ).

Comment: The greying out used to be much more significant, see [my post](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11207/62294) on RPG meta documenting some of the changes.

Comment: @Laurel who knows these days. Lots of things in the UI look like bugs but I guess aren't. Or aren't being fixed. I don't even know if there is a difference between these any more.

Comment: This is either a regression or another "accessibility update"; it's definitely affecting more sites than just SU. The tags on questions  with an ignored tag [are no longer greyed out with the post for me on Stack Overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o96Xf.png) either, where they definitely were yesterday.

Comment: I've edited based on assumption it's a [tag:bug]. Worst case, staff can retag again as [tag:support], or throw a [tag:status-bydesign] on it. But hopefully they'll simply fix it.

Comment: I'm fine with that. Question looks more convincing now that this really is not a wanted thing, in case a dev is trying to push a new uniformed look.

Comment: On a different site (e.g. [Anime.SE]), [the only indicators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1GDO.png) are the very subtle greyed text and "answer" box (and of course the crossed-eye icon, but it doesn't catch my attention better)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update 2022/09/13**: A fix for this issue has been released.

---

The tag and username colors are an issue with accessibility-related color changes on post summaries. Everything within an ignored post summary should be grayscale with the exception of post status badges (e.g. "Deleted") and user avatars.

Expect a fix to ship in the next couple days. Sorry for the trouble and thank you for catching this!

### The gritty details

Before recent accessibility-related color changes, we'd make elements within ignored and deleted post summaries grayscale with the CSS property `filter: grayscale(100%);`. We were targeting any and all elements this way (with an exception for some badges). This was the *easy* way to do it since we didn't need to override the styling of each element individually, but it was a blunt instrument and resulted in poor contrast for many elements and an overall lack of control over color values.

We're now applying specific colors (grayscale color values) for elements within ignored and deleted post summaries. This way we can make sure that all elements within these post summaries have ample contrast and consistent, chosen colors. The drawback is that we need to be more thorough when considering *any specific* element that can exist within these post summaries and apply additional CSS rules to style them appropriately, especially in cases where Stack Overflow and network sites diverge from what is intended by the design system. It's more difficult to develop but, regressions withstanding, results in improved accessibility and gives our designers more fine grained control over these color values.

Comment: But isn't the point of grayscaling them that they are easily skipped over. One doesn't intend to read those, so there is no need for a good contrast there. So your focus on checking all boxes presented to you by an expensive third party consultant seems quite counterproductive here.

Comment: @Luuklag In the options for ignoring, there's an option to either gray questions out or to hide them entirely. If one wants to just skip over them blindly, then they're expected to set the option to hide the questions. If someone doesn't set it that way, it means they want to look at them on occasion, and the change being made here makes that accessible.

Comment: Right now, its not doing what it is supposed to do, draw attention away. In fact, it amplify's the attention as they are now standing out. How weird, I give a tag the ignore status, and now it draws attention. Please, make it all gray again. It was great before. Making most items the same color as the rest really is not the way to go. Accessibility is especially why I make them all gray, and preferably also lighter. We really want to make it easy to read over them most of the time, but only read them sometimes.

Comment: @LPChip you missed the "next couple days" part. Code changes are rarely instant, they deploy the change, then at some point it's merged with other changes, and pushed to production in organized manner. Please re-visit the bug when the fix actually pushed. (Dan will hopefully update us when it happens)

Comment: @Dan I do see "rev 2022.9.13.42973" here on MSE, yet no change. Hopefully your changes weren't rejected somehow?

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I am aware of that. I read the suggested change and its my opinion that it may not be the solution we're after. The old situation where everything was grayed out but slightly less readable was ideal, because that allows one to easily filter it out with your own mind. I strongly feel that the new change with more contrast will destroy this mindset and that its still not usable.

Comment: @LPChip but we still didn't see the change. Dan said it's going to be "grayscale", so I was under the impression it would look the same as before, in general. If it won't, and really stand out less than before, we can start new feature request asking to change it.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard fair enough.

Comment: Fun fact: depending on the colour scheme of the site, the greyed out post can actually be darker and more visible than normal posts https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBznO.png (from tex.se)

Comment: ""*A fix for this issue has been released.*" it still doesn't make the ignored posts substantially different. [Here is RPG.SE](https://i.imgur.com/PjvIyuH.png) - the ignored posts seem more like they are *visited* rather than "don't pay attention". The body text is hardly distinguishable as greyed out. The grey box for answers just matches the colour scheme for other element - see "Newest" at the top which is *actually highlighted*. Ditto for the greyscale tags - they don't really stand *down*. The screenshot looks more like odd/even patterned than normal/suppressed.

Comment: I see no change at all. Not even tiny bit. Thanks for the effort, but it's just not what we asked for.

Comment: @LPChip you were correct, in the name of accessibility they sacrificed ignored tags and made a useful feature useless. Feel free to start the feature request and I'll upvote.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard I do see the change, but yes, this is exactly what I was afraid of. A really useful feature has been turned into something useless. I'll make a feature request. I'll mark this solved though. With a downvote obviously.

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard [My brain cannot ignore the ignored questions due to contrast change. Please change it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382047/my-brain-cannot-ignore-the-ignored-questions-due-to-contrast-change-please-chan)

Comment: Was the fix reverted? Yesterday I saw the tags were already greyed out, but today they are blue again.

Comment: @MetaAndrewT. yep, the tag fix was accidentally reverted in a most recently deployed version of our design system. We’ve reintroduced the fix in a next version that will be deployed by early next week. Sorry for the trouble!