# Accepted answer box; grey instead of green

Tags: bug, design, accepted-answer

A few days ago, the new styling made the accepted answer boxes dark green, as described in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/381858/why-has-the-green-accepted-answer-indicator-become-darker-on-all-the-sites).

---

Today, I saw a 'new' grey variant, with the 'accepted answer' icon:
[image]

<sub>[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4d6H.png) of all 3 different boxes</sub>

---

Is this a styling issue, or does it have a special meaning?

---

EDIT: It seems to be a bug, reloading the page shows a green box before turning grey
[GIF showing the page refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK2AS.gif)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is because you have one or more of the tags of the question in your Ignored Tags list, and you have "Gray out questions in your ignored tags" option selected.

[image: one of the tags is ignored]

Worth to mention, there was major change in the design of ignored items, as explained in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/381998/152859):

> We're now applying specific colors (grayscale color values) for elements within ignored and deleted post summaries

That's why it's very hard to notice the whole line is actually grayed out. If you want to have back what used to be before, see [My brain cannot ignore the ignored questions due to contrast change. Please change it back](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382047/my-brain-cannot-ignore-the-ignored-questions-due-to-contrast-change-please-chan).